# sed + remove the "#" character in case line appears

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

we have the following file:

```
   cat graphite-web.conf

   #<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.4
   #    Require local
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Allow from All
   #    Require all granted
   #</IfModule>
   #<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.2
   #    Require all granted
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Deny from all
   #    Allow from All
   #    Allow from ::1
   #</IfModule>
```

what is the best approach to remove the # before the line "Require all granted"

- the "#" character not in the beginning of the line

expected output:

```
   #<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.4
   #    Require local
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Allow from All
        Require all granted
   #</IfModule>
   #<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.2
   #    Require all granted
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Deny from all
   #    Allow from All
   #    Allow from ::1
   #</IfModule>
```

Comment: yes both are need to update

Comment: It looks to me like the `#` is at the beginning of the line (in the entire example); how do the lines change in the output if that's the case?

Comment: the # not in the begging , I saw the file and this # is couple spaces after the begging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**sed** solution:

```
sed 's/#\([[:space:]]*Require all granted\)/ \1/' graphite-web.conf
```

The output:

```
   #<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.4
   #    Require local
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Allow from All
        Require all granted
   #</IfModule>
   #<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.2
        Require all granted
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Deny from all
   #    Allow from All
   #    Allow from ::1
   #</IfModule>
```

---

To edit the file inplace - add `-i` option:

```
sed -i ....
```

Comment: how to use the flag -i in the sed syntax ? ( we want to edit the file in the command and not copy it )

Comment: @yael, see my note

Comment: sed -i  's/#([[:space:]]*Require all granted)/ \1/'  /tmp/install_zone/GRAPHITE/package/files/inst_files/graphite-web.conf
sed: -e expression #1, char 41: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: any suggestion regarding the "-i" in the sed ?

Comment: @yael, you have used my approach in wrong way: parenthesis should be escaped. `\(`